# Python: time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()) giving same time for the entire execution of the program. I want to show real time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, strftime

I want a solution so that the code gives real time in the output. Currently the code gives constant time during the entire execution. What module or method should be used for its solution? Thanks

My code is like this below:

```
import time

t = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())

i=0

print(t)
print(t)

while i<10000000:
  i+=1
  continue

print("***these statements below should give different time***")
print(t)
print(t)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
Fri, 28 May 2021 10:17:15
Fri, 28 May 2021 10:17:15
***these statements below should give different time***
Fri, 28 May 2021 10:17:15
Fri, 28 May 2021 10:17:15
Fri, 28 May 2021 10:17:15
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the time in `t`, then printing the stored value again. Try instead:

```
import time

i=0

print(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
print(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))

while i<10000000:
  i+=1
  continue

print("***these statements below should give different time***")
print(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
print(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
print(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
```

Alternatively, you could try making a shorthand function to avoid typing all that out:

```
import time

def t():
    print(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))

i=0

t()
t()

while i<10000000:
  i+=1
  continue

print("***these statements below should give different time***")
t()
t()
t()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might prepare *function* which will give `str` with current time when called and then use it, i.e.:

```
import time

def current_time():
    return time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())

i=0

print(current_time())
print(current_time())

while i<10000000:
  i+=1
  continue

print("***these statements below should give different time***")
print(current_time())
print(current_time())
print(current_time())
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good. However, to be less reduntant, you could use a function:

```
import time

def get_time():
    print(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))

i = 0

get_time()
get_time()

while i<10000000:
  i+=1
  continue

print("***these statements below should give different time***")
get_time()
get_time()
get_time()
```

Answer (score 0):

You, can try this:

```py
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
while True:
    now = datetime.now()  
    print ("%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s" % (now.month,now.day,now.year,now.hour,now.minute,now.second)) 
    sleep(1)
```